# Service takes more than a minute to close

Tags: linux, start-stop-daemon, adb

I have a Linux based device which is running certain services on boot-up, however one of them seems to be taking over a minute to close as I run `adb shell shutdown -h now` command.

Is there a way to tell what's causing this extra delay while the service is being shut down?

The following is a part of the daemon file that gets invoked as service are getting shut down...

```
start-stop-daemon -K -n /usr/bin/service
```

I see the following in logs

```
A stop job is running for service (1min 8s / 1min 15s)
A stop job is running for service (1min 11s / 1min 15s)
A stop job is running for service (1min 15s / 1min 51s)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no easy way to do it. Usually, the application shutdown procedure consists of dumping memory cashes, closing files, sending other processes "i am closed" messages etc. It all depends on the application and how it does the exit.

In case of `adb` - first of all, it tries to do a proper shutdown of all applications running inside. After that, it dumps its own caches and exit. The bottleneck here is most likely an app with memory leak or something similar. You would have to debug that app.

Comment: what determines 1min 15s time duration for the process to stop? it does eventually close and but it's just it takes long enough time